# drop down style in word document

Tags: drop-down-menu, cpu-word

How can I create a drop down list shown as left instead of right? the default style of the drop down option in the control section under developer tab is right. I couldn't find the style of the left. Thank you!
[image]

Comment: I think you have to check the ActiveX-Controls

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. The left is the drop down option in the legacy form, and the right is a normal  drop down under the developer tab. We only need to restrict the editing as "filling in forms" to get the legacy drop down shown as left.

[image]

otherwise, it's in the editing status, and will prompt the following window.

[image]